Couldnt find "Add Framework Support" to an existing intellj project

I am trying to add Maven into my existing project. The current version I am using is 2024.2.4 community edition, The Add Framework Support seems to be missing even though I double shift and search it word for word.
Do I have to enable some features in the settings in order to get it pop-up ?

FWIW Maven is not a framework, it's a build tool. It's likely enabled by default already in IntelliJ. Create a pom.xml and see what happens?

If you select the "Actions" tab in your view, you will find a checkbox "include disabled actions". The "Add Framework Support" entry might show up (which implies of course, there is another issue to solve, because it is disabled).
